# How to execute javascript code on current tab when focus?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

At the moment, each time a web page with certain criteria in its URL is open, automatically the `MercadoLibre.js` is executed inside that page.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://myaccount.mercadolibre.com.ar/sales/*"],
        "all_frames": false,
        "js":      ["MercadoLibre.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
```

<sup>I'm not exactly sure what means `all_frames`.</sup>

But I note that I don't want to execute that js file on each page when they are loaded. I just one to open on the current page with the criteria.

**How can I execute the code from `MercadoLibre.js` each time the user focus (click) on the tab which matches the criteria?**

I mean, now, if I open 5 pages with that criteria, all of them will be executed their scripts. My idea is only to execute the script each time I click them and get focus. I am not finding a way to achieve that.

Comment: I dont think you can do this directly as the onfocus event only works on elements not on the body. However, you can use the element in that particular page and add the code to it and run when the default focused element is in action.

Comment: You can register chrome.tabs.onActivated listener in your background script that will send a message via chrome.tabs.sendMessage. Your content script will receive it in chrome.runtime.onMessage and so it can proceed with whatever you want to do. You'll find more info by googling the terms I've mentioned.

Comment: [Specify Frames](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

The "all_frames" field allows the extension to specify if JavaScript and CSS files should be injected into all frames matching the specified URL requirements or only into the topmost frame in a tab.

Try using a focus listener to check for focus:

[onFocusChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255226/how-to-execute-javascript-code-on-current-tab-when-focus)
"Fired when the currently focused window changes."